# matplotlib month axis without horizontal align

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, backend

When I use matplotlib library to plot data with months in x axis, I have this problem

[image: months]

the months are without horizontal align, like that

```
sep           nov
       oct           dic
```

this way the axis look really ugly.

how I can solve this problem ?

### EDIT

if I use `baseline`

```
for tick in ax.xaxis.iter_ticks():
    tick[0].label1.set_verticalalignment('baseline')
```

I get

[image: label_baseline]

Comment: try setting the `verticalalignment` of the `xticklabels` to `baseline`

Comment: There is an [old `issue` about this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1734/), what version of `matplotlib` are you using?  Edit: Also, what backend are you using?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I use 1.2.1, in windows, I try to update

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I update the packages to matplotlib: 1.5.0, numpy: '1.9.3', with this I fix the problem, I get the packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix please you can make a answer with the comment to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be [an issue that has been fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1734/) with more recent versions of `matplotlib` --- make sure you are using an updated version.

For anyone that this is *still an issue for*, it [could be a problem with your backend](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4115).